# How to show my list-group-item one by one using setTimeout in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually i want to display `list-group-item` one by one using `setTimeout` in jquery.

Now it working fine but displaying together but i want to one by one. What i have tried described below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-group-item').each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).css('display', 'block');
        }, 2000);
     });
});
```

```css
.list-group { padding:10px; background:#f1f1f1;}
.list-group-item{display: none;}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">First item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fourth item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fifth item</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-group-item').each(function (key, val) {
        var self = $(this);
        $(self).css('display', 'none');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).css('display', 'block');
        }, (2000*key));
     });
});
```

```css
.list-group { padding:10px; background:#f1f1f1;}
.list-group-item{display: none;}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">First item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fourth item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fifth item</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much `Mosè Raguzzini`

Answer (score 2):

First, bootstrap is showing your `li`s so your code actually does nothing and your `display:none` is ignored in the css.  So you need to re- `hide()` them first.

Next, use the parameter for `each` which gives the index and multiply that by your timeout (starts at 0, so +1);

```
$(selector).each(function(i) {
```

Which gives:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-group-item').hide().each(function (i) {
       
        var self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).show();
        }, 500 * (i+1));
     });
});
```

```css
.list-group { padding:10px; background:#f1f1f1;}
.list-group-item{display: none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">First item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fourth item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fifth item</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
 </div>
```

---

An alternative to `500 * (i+1)` would be to keep looping while one is invisible and show the next one.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to increment the timeout function. I've used the index of the elements to do this. I also changed the CSS slightly to make it more specific (before the CSS wasn't being applied).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-group-item').each(function (i) {
        var self = $(this);
        var count = i;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).css('display','block');
        }, 2000 * count);
     });
});
```

```css
.list-group { padding:10px; background:#f1f1f1;}
.list-group .list-group-item{display: none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">First item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fourth item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fifth item</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use index from `each()` loop and multiply it with delay time.

```js
$('a.list-group-item').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * 300).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).addClass('show')
  })
});
```

```css
.list-group {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

a.list-group-item {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

a.list-group-item.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">First item</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fourth item</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fifth item</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use fadeIn(); fadeOut(); for transition effects

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.list-group-item').fadeOut().each(function (i) {
   
    var list = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(list).fadeIn();
    }, 300 * (i+1));
 });
});
```

```css
.list-group { padding:10px; background:#f1f1f1;}
.list-group-item{display: none;}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">First item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fourth item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fifth item</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
 </div>
```